# How does the Boot Camp Assistant force the Windows installer to prompt the user to choose an edition of Windows to install?

Tags: bootcamp, windows

When choosing to install Windows 7 using the Boot Camp Assistant, after files have been copied from the Windows ISO to a USB Flash drive, upon rebooting I've noticed that the Windows installer prompts the user to choose an edition that they would like to be installed - even if the source Windows ISO is of a specific edition (Home Premium, Ultimate, etc). How is this possible - does Boot Camp Assistant simply remove the "ei.cfg" file from the USB drive or similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest Windows 7 with SP1 ISO can be downloaded from the Microsoft website [Download Windows 7 Disc Images (ISO Files)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows7). After entering the product key for `Microsoft Windows 7 Professional Upgrade 32/64-bit (English)`, I was eventually lead to the page shown below. I downloaded the 64 bit Windows 7 ISO.

[image]

After mounting the ISO, I was able to determine that a  `ei.cfg` file does exist in the `sources` directory. The contents is shown below. The default is to install Windows 7 Professional.

```
[EditionID]
Professional
[Channel]
Retail
[VL]
0
```

According to [Install Windows 7 on your Mac using Boot Camp](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205016#version5), the Boot Camp Support Software includes an answer file named `AutoUnattend.xml`. The Microsoft document [Windows Setup Edition Configuration and Product ID Files (EI.cfg and PID.txt)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/windows-setup-edition-configuration-and-product-id-files--eicfg-and-pidtxt) states the following.

> **Note**   An answer file takes precedence over these files. If you use an answer file during installation, Windows Setup ignores the EI.cfg and PID.txt files.

Using the `Dism` command, provided by the [latest Windows 10](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO), produces the following list of images stored in the `sources\intall.wim` file on the Windows 7 ISO. Windows 7 Professional is the image with index of 3.

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.418]
(c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

X:\Sources>diskpart

Microsoft DiskPart version 10.0.18362.1

Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.
On computer: MINWINPC

DISKPART> list vol

  Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs     Type        Size     Status     Info
  ----------  ---  -----------  -----  ----------  -------  ---------  --------
  Volume 0     D   CCCOMA_X64F  UDF    CD-ROM      5170 MB  Healthy
  Volume 1     E   GSP1RMCPRXF  UDF    CD-ROM      2047 MB  Healthy

DISKPART> exit

Leaving DiskPart...

X:\Sources>Dism /Get-ImageInfo /imagefile:E:\sources\install.wim

Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 10.0.18362.1

Details for image : E:\sources\install.wim

Index : 1
Name : Windows 7 Home Basic
Description : Windows 7 Home Basic
Size : 11,710,161,360 bytes

Index : 2
Name : Windows 7 Home Premium
Description : Windows 7 Home Premium
Size : 12,222,587,449 bytes

Index : 3
Name : Windows 7 Professional
Description : Windows 7 Professional
Size : 12,122,886,417 bytes

Index : 4
Name : Windows 7 Ultimate
Description : Windows 7 Ultimate
Size : 12,285,492,779 bytes

The operation completed successfully.

X:\Sources>
```